# mariadb-client-core-10.5 : Depends: libreadline5 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable

Tags: mariadb, dependencies

I can not install mariadb-server. I run the following command:

**sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y**

The following message appears:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mariadb-client-core-10.5 : Depends: libreadline5 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix these dependecies?

Thanks in advance!!!

=========================================

**sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.5 -y**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mariadb-client-core-10.5 : Depends: libreadline5 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried with aptitude:

** sudo aptitude install mariadb-server **

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gawk{a} libsigsegv2{a} mariadb-server{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 434 kB of archives. After unpacking 1.772 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.5 (>= 1:10.5.15+maria~focal) but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     mariadb-server [Not Installed]                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y       
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gawk{a} libsigsegv2{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 430 kB of archives. After unpacking 1.761 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Get: 1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libsigsegv2 amd64 2.13-1ubuntu2 [14,6 kB]
Get: 2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 gawk amd64 1:5.1.0-1build1 [416 kB]
Fetched 430 kB in 1s (718 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libsigsegv2:amd64.
(Reading database ... 209196 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsigsegv2_2.13-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.13-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.13-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gawk.
(Reading database ... 209203 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gawk_1%3a5.1.0-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gawk (1:5.1.0-1build1) ...
Setting up gawk (1:5.1.0-1build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.34-0ubuntu3.2) ...
```

I have installed the client with aptitude:

** sudo aptitude install mariadb-client **

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-client{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 3.096 B of archives. After unpacking 10,2 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.5 (>= 1:10.5.15+maria~focal) but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     mariadb-client [Not Installed]                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

The client still does not connect....

```sql
Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.21.10.3, or
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.5  # version 1:10.5.15-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
juanma@juanma-HP-Laptop-17-ca1xxx:~$ mariadb
Command 'mariadb' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.5
juanma@juanma-HP-Laptop-17-ca1xxx:~$ sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.5 -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mariadb-client-core-10.5 : Depends: libreadline5 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks

============================================================

In the end I have done it with Docker and with a script and it has worked perfectly. Thank you all:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --name mariadbtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -p 3306:3306 -d docker.io/library/mariadb:10.3
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0
mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -p
```

Comment: Try: `sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.5`

Comment: It does not work. I have added the problem.

Comment: There is some missing info about your system. Which Linux distro are you using? and which version?  Why are you finally installing a different client ("mysql-client-core") then your title ("mariadb-client-core") suggests?

Comment: NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

In any case, it doesn't matter, he has solved it with docker

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have done it with Docker and with a script and it has worked perfectly. Thank you all:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --name mariadbtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -p 3306:3306 -d docker.io/library/mariadb:10.3
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0
mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -p
```